# How to create folder style in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a list of documents and i need to represent those documents in a graphical way, so i want to create something like the windows folder style. But i am poor with css. Some help would be apprecited

```css
.thread-reply-file {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.thread-reply-file {
  width: 80px;
  padding: 10px 8px 8px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: blue;
  float: left
}
.thread-reply-file span {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.thread-reply-file img {}
```

```html
<div title="Comments">
  <div class='thread-reply-file'>
    <img width='50' src='https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/CS5/128/ACP_PDF%202_file_document.png'>
    <span>Haneeq Mohamed</span>
  </div>
  <div class='thread-reply-file'>
    <img width='50' src='https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/CS5/128/ACP_PDF%202_file_document.png'>
    <span>Haneeq Mohamed</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Existing output**
[image: Existing]

**The way i want.**
[image: The way i want.]

Comment: [codepen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GjgpGZ);

Comment: If you are linking to actual files, you may be able to automate the icon representation using CSS wildcard selectors like `a[href$=".doc"]` - this would apply to a hyperlink with a suffix of `.doc` and from there you could apply the appropriate icon as a background image or via a pseudo-class selector like `:before`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does this look? Good luck!

Let me know if you have any clarifications on the code below:

```css
.thread-reply-file {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: blue;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80px;
}
.thread-reply-file span {
  display: block;
}
.thread-reply-file img {
  width: 50px;
}
div[title=Comments]:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div title="Comments">
  <div class='thread-reply-file'>
    <img src='https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/CS5/128/ACP_PDF%202_file_document.png'>
    <span>Haneeq Mohamed</span>
  </div>
  <div class='thread-reply-file'>
    <img src='https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/CS5/128/ACP_PDF%202_file_document.png'>
    <span>Haneeq Mohamed</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**:

Have kept a fixed `height` for each of the boxes and implemented multi-line `ellipsis` for the text. Adjust this `height` to suit your design:

```js
function ellipsizeTextBox(el) {
  var wordArray = el.innerHTML.split(' ');
  while (el.scrollHeight > el.offsetHeight) {
    wordArray.pop();
    el.innerHTML = wordArray.join(' ') + '...';
  }
}
var $this = document.getElementsByClassName('thread-reply-file');
for (var i = 0; i < $this.length; i++) {
  ellipsizeTextBox($this[i]);
}
```

```css
.thread-reply-file {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: blue;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80px;
  height: 85px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.thread-reply-file span {
  display: block;
}
.thread-reply-file img {
  width: 50px;
}
div[title=Comments]:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div title="Comments">
  <div class='thread-reply-file'>
    <img src='https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/CS5/128/ACP_PDF%202_file_document.png'>
    <span>Haneeq Mohamed</span>
  </div>
  <div class='thread-reply-file'>
    <img src='https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/CS5/128/ACP_PDF%202_file_document.png'>
    <span>Haneeq Mohamed</span>
  </div>
  <div class='thread-reply-file'>
    <img src='https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/CS5/128/ACP_PDF%202_file_document.png'>
    <span>This is a very long text and much longer than this</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when the length of the text increase, can we keep the size whole size fixed, currently its giving me different size boxes [link to image](http://imgur.com/BsnjI2q)   @kukkuz

Comment: while keeping height constant do you want to show the whole text or truncate it using `ellipsis`?

Comment: its better if we can truncate using ellipsis, increae the size of the box and have text length like 10 @kukkuz

Comment: have improved upon it to include you needs... check it out